# disabling button after clicking it

Tags: c#, winforms

i have here 3 buttons.

when i click on the button 1, it will disable button 1 then  enable the second button,  then same proces as it reach the last button. but i think there is something wrong with my code. it doesn't disable when i click on the first button

button1 is enabled and button2 and 3 is disabled when it loads.

```
private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;

    if (btn == button1)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = true;
        button3.Visible = false;
        button3.Enabled = false;
        MessageBox.Show("button 1 disabled");
    }
    else if (btn == button2)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = false;
        button3.Visible = true;
        button3.Visible = true;
        MessageBox.Show("button 2 disabled");
    }
    else if (btn == button3)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = false;
        button3.Visible = false;
        button3.Visible = false;
        MessageBox.Show("button 3 disabled");
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to using if-else statement why dont you invoking each buttons with same EventHandler method?

Comment: You need to use the `Click` events to trigger the changes and not `group_Enter`

Comment: Maybe checkboxes would be visually more intuitive for a sequence of operations.

Answer (score 4):

Are you subscribing to the right event?  It says groupBox1_Enter.

```
Button[] buttons = null;  // Initialize somewhere with all the buttons.

void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < buttons.Length; index++)
    {
        if (buttons[index] == sender)
        {
            buttons[index].Enabled = buttons[index].Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            buttons[index].Enabled = buttons[index].Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry I miss read your post.  In order below

```
Button[] buttons = null;
        void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int buttonIndex = Array.IndexOf(buttons, sender);
            for (int index = 0; index < buttons.Length; index++)
            {
                if (index == buttonIndex + 1)
                {
                    buttons[index].Enabled = buttons[index].Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    buttons[index].Enabled = buttons[index].Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: i just put it on a grouppanelbox, then use if-else statement.

Comment: @user1647667. The group box event is going to have a sender object of groupbox not button. You need to do like Mullaly posted

Answer (score 0):

Check what are the initial values of each button in the properties of each button.

Its better to have a Initializer to set the properties of the button before changing it.

Comment: I think @user1647667 is trying to do like this. `private void Button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 
 {

            groupBox1_Enter(sender, e);

 }


 private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   
 {

            
 {
  //Code
 }
}` I am not sure though!

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the code inside the `Enter` event of the `GroupBox`, this event will have the groupoBow as `sender`. Subscribe the `ButtonPressed` event of one of the button and eventually use the same generated method to subscribe the `ButtonPressed` event of the 2 other buttons (if you want to use the `if-else` statements as you wrote)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try it this way:

```
private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;

    if (btn == button1)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = true;
        button3.Enabled = false;
        MessageBox.Show("button 1 is disabled");
    }
    else if (btn == button2)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = false;
        button3.Enabled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("button 1 & button 2 are disabled");
    }
    else if (btn == button3)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = false;
        button3.Enabled = false;
        MessageBox.Show("button 3 disabled");
    }
}
```

is this the way you think it has to work or am i getting this wrong?